# Adding a timer to a simple php login time

Tags: php, timer

I want to know how to add a **timer** to a simple php login form for **displaying the time the user stays logged in** (priority)

Answer (score 0):

Track the duration with session variables. When the user logs in, record the time and stick it into a session variable. That will only happen at the point of login and will get erased when they logout.

Each time the page is refreshed, get the difference between the current time and the session timestamp - then do the multiplication to get the cost.

```
<?php
// session_start(); goes at the top of any page where you need to create or access session variables
session_start(); // you have to tell PHP to start the session before you add a session variable 

function login() {
  // do logic and log in the user
  // set a session variable
  if ($logged_in) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in_time'] = time();
  }
}

function logout() {
  // do logic and log OUT the user
  // clear the session variable
  unset($_SESSION['logged_in_time']);
}
```

Then in your header.php (or whatever UI facing php page)

```
<?php 
if ($is_logged_in) {
  // get the duration in minutes (time() is in seconds so we divide by 60 to get minutes) - and ceil() rounds the number with decimal to a whole number
  $duration_minutes = ceil((time() - $_SESSION['logged_in_time']) / 60);       
  $cost_per_min = 2/60; // get the cost per minute based on the $2 hourly rate
  $my_cost = $cost_per_min * $duration_minutes;
  if ($duration_minutes > (60 * 24) ) {
    // test to see if we need an 's' appended to our duration
    $s = ($duration_minutes/(60 * 24) > 1) ? "s" : "";
    $duration_display = toFixed($duration_minutes/(60 * 24), 1) . " day" . $s;
  } else if ($duration_minutes > 60) {
    $s = ($duration_minutes/60 > 1) ? "s" : "";
    $duration_display = ceil($duration_minutes/60) . " hour" . $s ;
  } else {
    // test to see if we need an 's' appended to our duration
    $s = ($duration_minutes > 1) ? "s" : "";
    $duration_display = $duration_minutes . " minute" . $s;
  }  
  $message = "You have been logged in " . $duration_display . " ($" . $my_cost . ")";
}
// in the above functions toFixed($value, 1) takes a number like 3.34567 and makes it 3.3
?>
```

html

```
<div class='cost_header'><?php echo $message?></div>
```